# How to sanitize text field with html in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, validation, sanitization

Hi my question is how to properly sanitize input field that contains html. Now I do:

`if( isset( $_POST[ 'obecnie' ] ) ) {
            update_post_meta( $post_id, 'obecnie', sanitize_text_field($_POST['obecnie' ]));
        }`

sanitize_text_field is a Wordpress function and it strips all html from input. What I need to achive is actually to allow user insert break tag or new line entity in input and display this in frontend.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[wp_kses](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_kses) strips HTML tags and attributes from a string *except the ones you whitelist* when you call it.

For example to only allow br tags and links with an href attribute (but no others, not even a style or title), you'd call it like:

```
$allowed_html = array(
  'a' => array(
    'href' => array(),
  ),
  'br' => array(),
);
$str = wp_kses( $str, $allowed_html );
```

Comment: Dave Ross - the question is if wp_kses does all the nessesary sanitization job with input value?

Comment: After wp_kses, you'll have a string that contains plaintext and the HTML tags + attributes you specify. It's certainly [good enough for WordPress VIP's code review standards](https://vip.wordpress.com/2011/10/13/key-differences-between-validation-and-sanitization/).

Comment: However, don't confuse sanitization with escaping. You'll still want to use one of the esc_* functions or wp_kses() again to escape the value when it's output.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about that wordpress function, but you can try this function sanitize htmlentities :

```
 htmlentities($_POST['obecnie' ]);
```

And then you can convert the user entered line breaks (actual line breaks, not BR tag), to BR tag before displaying anywhere, like this :

```
preg_replace('/[\n\r]/', '<br />',htmlentities($_POST['obecnie' ]));
```

And you also need to remember to revert the line breaks back if you are going to give the user edit option:

```
$textToBeShownInTextBox = str_replace('<br />',"\n", $textFromDb);
```